# 2D Graphics Performance Boost

Tags: c++, winapi

I know my title is a bit wishy-washy. My problem is this, I am trying to code a little game in C++ with Win32 graphics and I want all my pieces to be drawn from the top down so that they go in front of each other properly. (E.G., if I'm stood in front of a tree, it draws the tree first, then the player so I am in front)

My first idea was, using vectors as I needed a dynamic array type thing, to cycle in a for loop like this

```
for(y = 0; y < playerYValue; y++){
    //Check every enemy/object to see if its yValue matches the looping y
    object.drawImage();
}
```

And the same for in front of the player. However, after running some tests, this is very inefficient as with the looping, it takes 34 milliseconds, and without it takes 2 :/

I am looking for a way to draw all of my objects in order and would appreciate any help whatsoever, everything is worth a try. This is one area I just can't think of an inventive way to solve the problem.

Please ask if you need me to give more details :)

EDIT: The comment in the code is a placeholder for the vector iterations each time to check if the object's yValue is equal to y :) Thought I'd clear that up a bit :)

Comment: what are the contents of "object.drawimage()"?

Comment: drawImage() in this case is just a placeholder for the image drawing function. It's just a basic Win32 draw, nothing too special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should sort the objects by y value and then render them, this should be faster if you are currently doing a search on each object every time you draw an object.

And try not to make the player special. Player should be an "object" as well, then you would sort once back to front and then draw back to front.

Comment: Ok, well, all my "objects" are members of Entity for such reasons, so I could make a vector which encompasses everything. how would I go about sorting all my Entities by a variable? :) I know of the sort() algorithm, but I would think this would only sort by the name? (Thank you for the help, this is certainly food for thought!)

Comment: Also, if the player is included in this varying vector, how would I do all the specific things to it? Or should I try to make sure all specifities are handled within the class :)

Comment: @BradleyHodgkins Your latter suggestion is the ideal case, if you need to you could keep a `Player* myPlayer` to the player object, before you add it to the `Entity` list. Then use that pointer to operate on its specifics, such as player input etc. You should try to use overloading/inheritance to minimize the need for outside control as possible though

Comment: Ok thank you :) I'l give this a try later on :) I'll give you the answer because it sounds lie a great idea :)

Comment: Hey, sorry to bug you, this seems to have worked, but the pointer idea isn't working, unless you meant to add the pointer into the vector. My problem now is that something is being updated, but it's not the one in the vector! I'll google around to research the problem, but if you could explain what you meant some more that'd be much appreciated :)

Comment: @BradleyHodgkins is your vector one of pointers or objects? It should be pointers. And roughly it should go like this `Player myPlayer = new Player(); vector.push_back(myPlayer);`

Comment: Yes sorry, I spent a while playing around and worked this out, I forgot to message you back :) Thanks again :) Yeah, I had a vector of objects and I think I understad the ins and outs of why that wasn't working :) Again thank you, the time to draw is under 4 milliseconds even with 30 enemies and 10 pieces of scenery :P This was unthinkable with my previous atrocity of code :)